# Re-arrange HashMap keys in custom pre-defined order

Tags: java, sorting, hashmap

I have an `HashMap<String, String>` that I need sorted in a specific order.
I understand HashMaps,
because of how they are constructed,
cannot be easily sorted.
However,
I am looking for the best strategy to re-arrange the keys in my HashMap - for example my current HashMap looks like this:

```
"folioProperties": {
    "strategy": "Strategy",
    "summary": "Summary",
    "initiative": "Initiative",
    "deliveryMilestone": "Delivery Milestone",
    "onTarget": "On Target",
    "size": "Size",
    "driver": "Driver",
    "issueName": "Issue Name",
    "releaseWindow": "Release Window",
    "type": "Type",
    "targetQuarter": "Target Quarter"
}
```

I have a table view that shows each of these properties as columns and I need to order the columns/hashmap by `Strategy, Initiative, Issue Name, Summary, Delivery Milestone, On Target, Size, Target Quarter, Driver, Type, Release Window`.

Any suggestions would be appreciated!

P.S. Before the HashMap is constructed, the keys are in a `List<String>`.

Comment: Use a `LinkedHashMap`.

Comment: @Eran-- I think OP is asking about sorting not ordering, so I think TreeMap would be best option here

Comment: Check this out, i think it will help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23365307/java-treeset-order

Comment: `LinkedHashMap` preserves insertion order, so that seems like the easiest road to take, unless you want to create your own `Comparator` that preserves ordering.

Comment: In terms of using a `LinedHashMap`, is there a dynamic way of insertion or do I just manually insert each key as I want?

Comment: @FJJunior: Depends on the source of the data you want to put in the map. In general, the first thing you put into a `LinkedHashmap` will be the first thing returned by an iterator of it and so forth.

Comment: @Henrik gotcha. It seems that would probably be the best option. The custom Comparator seems it may complicate things a little more. When converting a `HashMap` into a `LinkedHashMap`, is there a best practice to follow?

Comment: @FJJunior: Well, there is a constructor that accepts another map as input, but that will defeat the purpose of ensuring ordering, so.... I suggest you do it the "brute-force" way, and then beautify later or create a new question regarding improving it.

Comment: As a comment, you can "implement" a custom comparator from Java 8 as a lambda `(e1, e2) -> e1.compareTo(e2)` supossing that you implement a correct `compareTo` method. But for you case, where you have predefined order, it's easier to use a `LinkedHashMap`.

Comment: "When converting a HashMap into a LinkedHashMap" don't convert put your data in a `LinkedHashMap` directly from `List<String>` in the correct order.

Comment: @Henrik, thanks for the help - ended up using the `LinkedHashMap`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems that you do not understand the problem that you are attempting to fix.
The hashmap is a tool for storing information.
It seems likely that you never actually need to sort the hashmap.
Instead,
it seems likely that you need to display elements in a specific order.

Here are two ways to retrieve the elements from the hashmap in a specific order:

#### Retrieve the elements in the desired order

```
blam = map.get("strategy");
... do something with blam.

blam = map.get("Initiative");
... do something with blam.

... repeat for all elements.
```

#### Sort the keys then retrieve them in order

```
keyList.addAll(map.keySet());
Collections.sort(keyList, yourComparator);
for (final String current : keyList)
{
    blam = map.get(current);
    ... do something with blam.
}
```

#### Stop representing an object as a Map

Build a class,
perhaps named FolioProperties,
that represents the properties of the Folio.

```
public class FolioPropertiesFND
{
    private String initiative;
    private String strategy;
    ... one field per property.

    public String getInitiative()
    {
        return initiative;
    }

    public void setInitiative(final String newValue)
    {
        initiative = newValue;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If your data is in an ordered list prior to the map construction, then what you need is a `java.util.LinkedHashMap`

from the javadoc:

> Hash table and linked list implementation of the Map interface, with predictable iteration order. This implementation differs from HashMap in that it maintains a doubly-linked list running through all of its entries. This linked list defines the iteration ordering, which is normally the order in which keys were inserted into the map (insertion-order).
>
> This implementation spares its clients from the unspecified, generally chaotic ordering provided by HashMap (and Hashtable), without incurring the increased cost associated with TreeMap

If you use a LinkedHashMap, then all you have to do is to put the key/value pairs in the correct order and the map will ensure the same iteration order for you.